# Drag and Drop FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, drag-and-drop, android-framelayout

I am wanting to have a group of components that are draggable...

eg.. 1 TextView, 1 EditText, & 1 Button

I have put these into a FrameLayout and want to be able to drag and drop them around the parent layout.

Can it be done? and can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tutorial here (note: have not tried it):

http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/drag-and-drop-ui-element/

Let us know if it works.

Comment: Great, works with TableLayout (changed my mind from FrameLayout) .. much appreciated.

Comment: @Tony Can you please share the code for your drag and drop TableLayout project. I am strugling with the same problem as you and your code would really helped me out.